# Why does Kyle XY not have a navel?

Tags: kyle-xy

I admit that I never watched the show, but for some reason I am curious about this. Was this ever answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because he wasn't born. He was grown in a lab.

It's similar to why the genie from [I Dream of Jeannie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Dream_of_Jeannie) didn't have a navel.

Edit: added my line about I Dream Of Jeannie back in so TangoOversway's comments made sense.

Comment: Jeannie had a navel.  Censors just didn't allow it to be seen.  _The Making of Star Trek_ and _The World of Star Trek_ discuss this.  In the 60s NBC had serious issues with women's navels.

Comment: Jeannie had a Mother and Father and an evil twin sister?  It's also explained Jeannie was born a human and changed into a genie by the Blue Djinn when she refused to marry him.  There's also this: <http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058815/trivia?tr=tr0787112> indicating it was a censorship concern, not part of the plot.  (If it were a plot issue, then the concern at that point would be from producers, not censors.)  (And in one of the books I reference, there's a discussion about how it was a big deal to the NBC censors.)

Comment: Did they include footage from the show where such a statement was made?  Or did they just make the statement about the show?  (The "turned into a genie" story was also repeated much later in one of the made-for-TV movies.)

Comment: Am I missing soemthing - I fail to see the connection between the two shows being discussed.

Comment: @HorusKol: The original answer claimed Jennie of "I Dream of Jeannie" did not have a navel because she was not born.  Since then, he's edited the answer and removed his related comments.

Comment: Yep. I don't know enough about I Dream of Jeannie to continue the discussion, so I just removed it from the answer.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: I kind of wish you had left it -- I hope I wasn't being confrontational, and it's a good point if questions about that series ever came up.  (I just had a serious crush on Barbara Eden when the show was on, so I know it a little too well...)