# Why did a lab-grown human not have a navel?

Tags: kyle-xy

In a previous question, I asked [why Kyle XY did not have a navel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/why-does-kyle-xy-not-have-a-navel). According to the answer, it seems that this was because he was grown in a lab.

However, I still see no reason for why a human being grown in an artificial womb should lack a navel. The [umbilical cord is physiologically and genetically part of the fetus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilical_cord) (presumably in the case of Kyle XY this was attached to some kind of apparatus).

Was there ever any explanation for this? Was Kyle XY not actually human?

Comment: Not only is the umbilical cord *part* of the fetus - but a fetus cannot use its still-developing lungs, intestines, or kidneys to take in nutrients and oxygen and expel carbon dioxide and other waste. The umbilical cord, connected directly to the fetal circulation, is the only conduit by which all these *can* enter and leave the fetus.

Comment: another work, Space: Above and Beyond, have the cloned/tank-grown humans' "navel" in the back of their neck - could be the same with Kyle XY?

Comment: @HorusKol Interesting! In-universe, still seems like a lot of extra work to go through genetically modifying humans to develop an umbilical at the neck. I guess the reality is that science fiction writers can be just as ill-informed as the rest of us :)

Comment: @FrankPierce - in-universe, yeah - story-wise, it was a useful marker to allow for differentiation and discrimination of the "tanks"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to border the obvious here, but the act of growing a human in a lab is a fancy bit of science fiction (that's why we're here).

That said, it might be possible that a fetus being grown in a lab within a supportive fluid, that is, a fluid with sufficient life sustaining properties (nutrients, oxygen etc), could be genetically engineered such that it was able to perform the proper molecular exchanges through its skin.

Comment: Wch would thyen imply he wasn't simply a human.

Comment: Human is as human does.

Comment: It would still be much easier and more convenient to feed him through the umbilical cord, rather than any other method to force the fetus to survive without it.

Comment: That is true. I am just attempting to offer a logical in-universe explanation. If someone has actual canon evidence of another in-universe reason I'd welcome it. More likely is that someone on the production staff thought it would be cool to have the character with no belly-button, with no regards to what would technically be easier in fact.

Comment: If what you really believe is that the production staff just didn't think of it, then shouldn't be the answer? Seems to me that answers should be our best attempt at the truth - and if the truth is that there is no in-universe explanation given, then that should be the answer.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Had I a reference to confirm what I _think_ the out of universe answer is, then I would very happily add that to my answer. Lacking that, I prefer to go with a well reasoned in-universe answer.

Comment: +1 I appreciate the attempt at an in-universe explanation. This question popped in my head the other day and I thought it would be a fun topic!

Answer (score 4):

This was directly addressed in the show's second series.

Massive spoilers below, obviously.

> Second season episodes explain that Kyle was an experiment (XY) based on Einstein's theory that the longer an embryo stays in the womb the smarter it will be. A man named Adam was the only survivor of the first such experiment (at this time, the surrogate mothers, who carried the child for 13 months, died in childbirth; the infants died shortly after). Adam knew his past and wanted to create a world of geniuses. **He experimented and created a birth chamber with a pink fluid that could sustain life until the embryo reached an adult stage. Kyle was such an experiment** — the first since Adam to survive. 
>  
>  <sub><sup>[The Year in Television, 2009: A Catalog of New and Continuing Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786458445)</sup></sub>

So there you go. It was

> the fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Because in such science fiction, the objective is to present some subtle, but obvious once exposed, difference. The reason for this is to allow easier discriminatory behavior, which is then made use of in the setting for a variety of discrimination stories.

While I'm not overly familiar with *Kyle X/Y*, the same type of change is used in several other stories, including *Space: Above and Beyond*, where they moved it to the back of the neck.